# Set custom font to text recognizer(OCR) in mobile vision api android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, android-vision, google-vision

I'm developing an application that allows you to scan checks, I tested with Tesseract and it works, I wonder if you can train text recognition api mobile vision to recognize the typography of a check

Comment: Hi any news on this feature? I am also searching on this kind of requirement. Please let me know if you found something.

Comment: I did not find anything, I used Tesseract

Comment: @Brandon V Mariñelarena ................I guess you mentioned cheque instead of check...... We have read micr images in cheque using OpenCV and tesseract.......However it increases the size of the application and is a big headache to build OpenCV............